How can I use the State monad, or the StateT monad transformer, to mimic the IO monad for testing functions that run in a IO-based monadic stack?
Using State as an alternative to IO in testing
Take a simple function like this
foo :: IO ()
foo = putStrLn "ciao"

This is not testable, because it affects the state of the terminal, which I can't write a test for.
Using the approach suggested here, one can rewrite the above in terms of a generic monad m constrained by a typeclass, say named IOLike, which requires implementers, one of which is IO itself, to define putStrLn.
In code this means we define this class,
import Prelude hiding (putStrLn)
class IOLike m where
  putStrLn :: String -> m ()

write the trivial implementation for IO,
import Prelude hiding (putStrLn)
import qualified Prelude as P (putStrLn)
instance IOLike IO where
  putStrLn = P.putStrLn

write the desired implementation for the State monad that is used to mimic IO in testing,
import MTLPrelude
instance IOLike (State String) where
  putStrLn str = modify' $ \s -> s ++ str

With the above code in place, we can change foo's definition to
foo :: IOLike m => m ()
foo = putStrLn "ciao"

which can now be used both in the IO monad by production code,
main :: IO ()
main = do
  foo

and in the State monad by testing code
main :: IO ()
main = do
  P.putStrLn $ foo `execState` ""

where "" is the intial state of the string that represents the state of the terminal. P.putStrLn should be changed to some assertion made for instance via QuickCheck.

So far so good, but...
How to use State as an alternative to a IO-based monadic stack?
But now say that we have another function, bar, which is meant to run in a more complex monad with a MonadIO at the base of a monadic stack, e.g.
bar :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader String m) => m ()
bar = do
  e <- ask
  liftIO $ P.putStrLn $ "ciao" ++ show e

which would run in the IO monad,
main :: IO ()
main = do
  bar `runReaderT` "env"

Again, I would like to change bar so that it runs in any IOLike monad:
bar :: (IOLike m, MonadReader String m) => m ()
bar = do
  e <- ask
  putStrLn $ "ciao" ++ show e

The problem is that the above can't even be run in the IO monad,
main :: IO ()
main = do
  bar `runReaderT` "env"

because it errors with No instance for ‘IOLike (ReaderT String IO)’, let alone trying to run it in the State monad that is meant to play, in testing code, the role of IO,
main :: IO ()
main = do
  P.putStrLn $ bar `runReaderT` "env" `execState` ""

because this errors too, with No instance for ‘IOLike (ReaderT String (StateT String Identity))’.

It's clear that the problem is that having State String implement IOLike doesn't imply that any monadic stack with a StateT String m layer in it is an IOLike too.
I guess the solution would consist in writing an instance expressing the idea that any monadic stack with a StateT String layer is a IOLike, but how can I do that?
I've tried changing the original instance I wrote for State String to the following:
instance (MonadState String m) => IOLike m where
  putStrLn str = modify' $ \s -> s ++ str

but what I get is this error:
 • The constraint ‘MonadState String m’
     is no smaller than the instance head ‘IOLike m’
 • In the instance declaration for ‘IOLike m’
 • Perhaps you intended to use UndecidableInstances


If you leave your original instance IOLike (State String) alone but also add this, then it works:
instance (Monad m, IOLike m) => IOLike (ReaderT r m) where
  putStrLn = lift . putStrLn


This works in the specific example I made, but as stated in the title and in the body of the question, I'm interested in the case of a generic monadic stack with IO at the bottom; with reference to your solution, I would need to add another instance if, say, if bar was a MonadWriter too.

@Enlico That's a known downside of monad transformer stacks. See Writing a Monad Transformer, does it really need so many hardcoded instances for details and alternatives.

Ouch, I see this matter is complex a lot! I've just realized that if StateT is one of the monadic layers, I have one more problem, i.e. the instance I'd write according to your suggestion and the instance I already have for State would overlap. I suppose an easy solution to this is to roll MyOwnState monad to be made, instead of State instance of IOLike for the purpose of faking IO, and treat StateT/ReaderT/etc all the same.

I think in this case it should be enough to define instance (Monad m, IOLike m, MonadTrans t) => IOLike (t m) ?

@NaïmFavier, maybe I'm just confused by your "in this case"... I guess yours is an alternative answer to the one above? Regarding the concern in my previous comment, that would still hold even with your suggestion, right?

Did you try it? It seems to work. AFAICT there's no overlap because there's no IOLike Identity instance.

@NaïmFavier, yes, I get Overlapping instances for IOLike (StateT String Identity) between instance (Monad m, IOLike m, MonadTrans t) => IOLike (t m) and instance IOLike (State String) for P.putStrLn $ foo `execState` "".

Right. You can mark the instance OVERLAPPABLE I guess.
